# Is Google maps new URL just an htaccess mod?

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-maps, url, url-rewriting

Google recently changed it's URL schema for maps:

https://www.google.com/maps/preview/@42.3654344,-71.0567709,21z

They are using pretty clean url's now with the use of @ and commas. Is this just an .htaccess mod?

Comment: It's probably a rewrite of some sort. But not likely to use apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't use apache. The entire Google platorm runs on a custom linux-based webserver called **Google Web Server** (or "gws"). It's proprietary so I don't know if there's htaccess or some similar functionality, but if I were to guess, because of the load and the sheer amount of traffic that Google gets, they're not likely to use an inefficient solution like htaccess anyways.

Comment: is htaccess really the inefficient? any benchmark data I can look at?

Comment: @MilkMan Don't have benchmarks, but this is what [Apache says about htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html): **You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.**

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'm looking into how to use directory blocks now. Appreciate the input